# Invalid character in header content ["x-cypress-file-path"] in Cypress

Tags: npm, cypress, automation-testing

I have some strange issue in Cypress. When I go to the Cypress automation toll, click Settings and then try to click Project settings, I get the following error:

> Invalid character in header content ["x-cypress-file-path"]
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["x-cypress-file-path"]
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:666:3)
> at j (:4526:1236)
> at Server. (:4526:1875)
> at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1072:12)
> at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)

My Cypress version in 13.3.3 (the last one) but the issue appears in the oldest versions as well. Here is the screenshot of the problem. What could be the issue?

[image]

I have tried to use different versions of Cypress. I expect to resolve the issue and be able to click see Project settings.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem in the configuration file `cypress.config.js`, specifically the [fileServerFolder - root project folder](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders--Files) setting.

This is used when the Cypress proxy handles a response, using this code:

```js
const args = _.compact([
  fileServerFolder,            // from config 
  req.url,                     // from request
])

const file = decodeURI(url.parse(path.join(...args)).pathname)

res.setHeader('x-cypress-file-path', file)   // error occurs here
```

The other external value is the request URL, which you can check in the Network tab of devtools for anything suspicious (i.e odd characters)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply. As I cannot find  fileServerFolder - root project folder, could you please tell me what and where should I change to solve the issue? Just starting with Cypress, so it's quite difficult for me at this stage :))

Comment: It's the folder where the application is served from. In a standard Vue app, it's the root folder of the project, and that's the default for the `fileServerFolder` setting so normally you don't need to set it. But if your folder structure is non-standard, you need to set it to tell Cypress where to look for the Vue components.